# how to add hyperlink in React Prime DataTable?

Tags: reactjs, datatable, primereact

I have a datatable and im using react prime library for that,
my requirement is to add a link in one specific column.

```
 <DataTable
        paginator
        rows={tableRowPage}
        value={products}
        tableStyle={{ minWidth: "30rem" }}
      ><Column
                key={field}
                field={field}
                header={header}
                style={{ width: "25%" }}
              />
   </DataTable>
```

I need hyperlink in specific cell

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue in the data table, and unfortunately, from my research, it appears that they do not offer support for it.

However, I have managed to solve this problem this way:

**Logic for adding Link in Data Table:**

```
<Column
  field="code"
  header="Code"
  body={(rowData) => {
    return (
      <div
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            color: "#3F00FF",
            textDecoration: "underline",
            cursor: "pointer",
            "&:hover": {
              color: "#23297A",
            },
          }}
          onClick={() => window.open("www.google.com", "_blank").focus()}
        >
          {rowData.code}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }}
></Column>;
```

I've rendered the data using the `body` in the Column component of Prime React. I applied CSS to style it as a link and added an onClick event for redirection.  You can modify logic according to your requirement.

Full code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-demo-forked-kqtdvs?file=/src/App.jsx

Let me know, If you've any further question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`body`](https://primereact.org/datatable/#api.Column.props.body) attribute of the `Column` component. Something like:

```js
<Column
   header='My Header'
   field='linkText'
   body={rowData => {
     return(
      <a href={`https://www.example.com/${rowData.url}`} >
         {rowData.linkText}
      </a>
   }}
   />
```

I'm using this to place buttons and whatnot. I don't see a reason it shouldn't work for a link.